# Android Studio Gradle version - Gradle version 2.8 is required

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I'm trying to build an Android project but the following error occurred

```
Error:(10, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Gradle version 2.8 is required. Current version is 2.4. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\...\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

It seem something's wrong with the `Gradle` version, however I checked the `gradle-wrapper-property` and it's already 2.10.

Also in File-Project Structure-Project, `gradle-version` is also 2.10

No idea how this happened, I've also restarted android-studio many times.

Comment: what happens if you start the build from the command line?

Comment: is this problem solved? I don't see that you mark any answer as solved

Comment: make sure android studio is using the wrapper gradle not the build in android studio one, preferences->gradle->check "use gradle wrapper"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the version of android studio from 1.4 to 1.5.1 fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 10):

For those that still need help, an answer on another post did it for me [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34814536/1843235).

You need to change **Settings > Builds,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle >Gradle** home path

Or set Use default gradle wrapper and edit `Project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` files field `distributionUrl` like this

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Comment: Change "Settings > Builds,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle >Gradle" works. I've tried changing "gradle-wrapper.properties", then doing File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart, but the problem persist.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that changing Gradle tools to version `1.5.0` is necessary, but if you're using `2.0-snapshot` or `beta` version of gradle, I recommend you to change it to `1.5.0`.

This error:

> ```
> Error:(10, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
>    > Gradle version 2.8 is required. Current version is 2.4. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in
> ```
>
> C:\Users...\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to
>   gradle-2.8-all.zip

only tells you that your project's Gradle system is a bit outdated and need to be updated to newer version.

Open your project `Android Studio` and in navigator on the left find file called `gradle-wrapper.properties`. It should have a content like this:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

Change the last line with `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip`

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Go To Android Preference and Just change Project level Settings to Use default gradle wrapper (recommended).

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in version checking in older android plugins. To fix this you can either go back to gradle 2.9 or use the newer plugin

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
```

But I see from your error message that it tries to run with gradle 2.4 so this is maybe another problem.

Comment: I tried to change to this but it says cannot find gradle:1.5.0
I then try to update android-studio from 1.4 to 1.5.1. It worked