# "Gradle Version 2.10 is required." Error

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

As I've been using

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
```

In the **build.gradle** file, I got the following error since **gradle version 2.10** has been released.
The error is :

> Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If
>   using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in
>   C:\Users\blahblah\myproject\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties
>   to gradle-2.10-all.zip

at first it looks easy to solve by the guide, but when I'd done the change, I got the error again.

I'm using **Android Studio 2.0** with the latest **Android SDK Tools 24.4.1** and **Android SDK Build Tools 23.0.2**

I've even tried to download **Gradle 2.10** and put it manually on android-studio\gradle\ folder, but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check [this updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37267191/2826147)

Comment: check the following solution with 3 different options https://stackoverflow.com/a/51496236/2003526

Answer (score 400, accepted):

You need to change **File > Settings > Builds,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle >Gradle home** path

On Mac OS, change the path in **Android Studio > Preferences > Builds,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle >Gradle home**

Or set **Use default gradle wrapper** and edit `Project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` files field `distributionUrl`  like this

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Comment: Switching to "default" solved this for me also. The pointed to file in the error already was modified as suggested, so it was confusing!

Comment: and dont forget a 'gradle sync' after doing so.

Comment: In mac the path is: Android Studio > Preferences > Builds,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle

Comment: This is not working for me. My gradle-wrapper.properties already has this line and I still get the error every time.

Comment: Second option (setting default gradle wrapper AND editing gradle-wrapper.properties) worked for me. Please keep in mind that if you don't have gradle 2.10 installed on your computer, it might take some time to download and build (25 minutes on my computer). And, as kellogs said, you MUST sync again after that.

Comment: This is a good useful anwer. However downloading the zip, and extracting the files onto a directory was necessary for me.

Comment: how can you set it to default? I'm using Android Studio thanks. I don't have any options from my project-level settings.

Comment: @MorZa your comment really ought to be edited right into the text of the answer.  On the mac, I did almost exactly what the answer said, File > [Other] Settings > Default Settings > Builds,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle .. and then went searching in the Service directory path... almost lost extra time there. Thanks for the comment

Comment: @MarBar doing both as you said, setting Default wrapper and editing still failed for me.   Updating the distributionURL does nothing, so I wonder if something else is overriding, methinks I must quit Android Studio.  I've never used gradle before this project (hired into gradle project), but I'm attempting to set all the configurations to make sense and be clean, but it's really still feeling like Eclipse.

Comment: Can't the Android Studio team provide a bug-less update for once?? Jesus!!

Comment: My project is already set to use the default Gradle wrapper, and the distributionUrl is already set as specified, and I'm still getting this error.

Comment: I have tried this in 100 different ways and the error always repeats. This is now Android 2.2.1 and I get Error:Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.14.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in E:\projects\joxpAndroid\Health@Home\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-1.10-all.zip.

Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
Migrate to Gradle wrapper and sync project  and no matter what one does, the gradle-1.10 always comes up. I have no idea where Android Studio is getting that from.

Comment: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip` works for me.

Answer (score 86):

Open Preference and search for Gradle or Navigate to **Builds, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle**

Then change Project-Level setting to `Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)`

Or keep local gradle distribution option and set *Gradle home to /.../gradle-2.10*

[image: Preference screen - Gradle]

> Make Sure that Gradle version is already setup to 2.10 in Module Settings

On the Project Window, right click on your project then select `Open Module Settings` (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>)

[image: Open Module Settings Project > Gradle version and enter 2.10]

**Update**

*Gradle Version: 3.3*
*Android Plugin version: 2.3.1*

Answer (score 51):

An easier way to accomplish this is to go to:
**Open Module Settings (your project) > Project > Gradle version** and enter 2.10

Comment: Changing the path didn't work because I didn't have gradle 2.10 (accepted answer) but this did

Comment: I don't have Gradle version field to set. Does anybody know where is it in IntelliJ 2016?

Comment: This is on Android Studio (although the IDE's are quite similar). On Project Structure you can just enter the version number you want - for example, 2.10.

Answer (score 41):

Download the latest gradle-3.0-all.zip from

http://gradle.org/gradle-download/

download from Complete Distribution link

open in android studio file ->settings ->gradle

open the path and paste the downloaded zip folder gradle-3.0 in that folder

change your gradle 2.8 to gradle 3.0 in file ->settings ->gradle

Or you can change your gradle wrapper in the project

edit YourProject\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties file and edit the  field distributionUrl in to

distributionUrl=   https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.0-all.zip

Comment: Android studio can sometimes be slow at downloading those files. You saved me the pain of waiting. Thanks

Comment: There is no Settings item in the File menu of Android Studio.  There are:

|Other Settings > | Default Settings…
|                 | Default Project Structure…
|--------------
|Import Settings…
|Export Settings…

Which one do you mean?

Comment: if you are using mac then it will be preferences->gradle

Comment: Besides the useful posted answers and the one voted as best answer, this step of downloading the zip and extracting the files onto a directory was necessary for me.

Comment: my Android Studio not even allowed me to choose the default gradle wrapper (it was dimmed/disabled) in the Settings under Menu. I need to download and extract the zip file to \gradle directory, and pointed to that directory.

Comment: Jackson Chengalai - there is no preferences->gradle on mac version - any other suggestions for making this change on OSX?

Comment: Works fine adding distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip in gradle-wrapper.properties and sync project again, is not necesary modify gradle path in android studio.

Answer (score 15):

For people who are using Ionic/Cordova framework, we need to change the `distributionUrl` in `GradleBuilder.js` file to `var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip';`

The `GradleBuilder.js` locates at `project/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js`

Answer (score 11):

First Check your  **Project-level settings** at

> File > Settings > Build, Executions, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle

and Select the Option :

- Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)

then go to Project's

> Gradle > wrapper > gradle-wrapper.properties

and edit version of the distributionUrl

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip

And you are done :)

Answer (score 10):

For Android studio v2.1

Follow these easy steps from images.

1. Go "File" and click "Project structure".[image: Opening project structure settings for the project]
2. Then select "Project" from left menu and then change "Gradle version" to the version your sdk manager has installed. In my case it is 2.10 so i change version to 2.10 and then click on "Ok". And then android studio automatically do gradle sync again and error was fixed.[image: Changing gradle version to the latest installed version for the project]

Answer (score 8):

Easiest way for me to fix this issue:

1. close IDE.
2. delete "gradle" folder
3. re-open project.

Answer (score 3):

The Android build system uses the Android Plugin for Gradle to support building Android applications with the Gradle build toolkit. The plugin runs independent of Android Studio so the plugin and the Gradle build system can be updated independently of Android Studio.

> Use gradle wrapper (recommended) - select this option to use Gradle
>   wrapper. Using Gradle wrapper lets you get automatic Gradle download
>   for the build. It also lets you build with the precise Gradle version.
>
> Newer versions of the Gradle plugin may require newer versions of
>   Studio to enable the new features in the IDE, but the project should
>   open in older versions of Studio, and build from there (since Gradle
>   does the build). We will be very careful about this.

```
Click on Settings -> Build -> Execution -> Deployment ->
Gradle -> Select  default gradle wrapper
```

**You can use**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'  // or alpha2
Or //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue before.

In the end, the problem is that you use terminal; it uses system config.

check it, whether you have set

```
"GRADLE_HOME=.\gradle-2.10"
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

For those who uses ionic, go to 
`[project name]/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js` 
on line 164 you will see the following: 
`var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip';`
This line is used to create your `gradle-wrapper.properties`, so any changes to the `gradle-wrapper.properties` wont matter. All you need to do is change the url to the latest version, sync the gradle and the problem is solved.

Just want to change the gradle version in the Android studio, go to `File>settings>project` and change the gradle version. After you apply, it will sync the project and you are ready to build.

Answer (score 3):

If the problem persist, add the following code in the build.gradle of the top project.

```
buildscript {
System.properties['com.android.build.gradle.overrideVersionCheck'] = 'true'

...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Important:

If you are getting this when you run:
 `gradle build`
 from command line you have to use:
 `gradlew build`
 instead so that you will use gradle wrapper to downloaded the appropriate  gradle version needed by the app.

When you execute `gradle build` you are using the global gradle installed on your system.

Answer (score 2):

Go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> choose `Use default gradle wrapper`

Answer (score 2):

for me all previous solutions failed, so i just edited

```
Project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties -> field distributionUrl 
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `change Prefrences > Builds,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle >Gradle home path`

Or set Use default gradle wrapper and edit Project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties files field distributionUrl like this

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip

Answer (score 1):

My problem maybe is different,so I just wanna tell somebody who may have the same problem as me.

I solved this problem by change Terminal path.
when I run `gradle clean`, the error come cross "`Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.2.1`".

I checked .gradle directory in my project, there are two versions in it: 2.2.1, 2.10.

when I run `gradle -v`, it shows my current version is 2.2.1.
I change my system environment `GRADLE_HOME` to `2.10` root directory, then I restart terminal in AS and run 'gradle -v', it still shows the current verision is 2.2.1.

open setting -> terminal change the cmd.exe path to the System32/cmd.exe.
then restart terminal, run `gradle clean`,everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had Android Studio version 1.5.1 installed and was running into this error. I have the following buildscript (which was working on Ubuntu but not Windows):

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}
```

I tried:

1. `gradlew clean`
2. Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)
3. Use local distribution and linked to downloaded gradle 2.2.1 binary

None of these solutions worked unfortunately. It should be worth noting that upgrading Android Studio from 1.5.1 to 2.1.1 also failed with errors about 2.10 missing so could not be performed.

**Solution:** What I ended up doing was simply downloaded the latest stable version of Android Studio and installing that instead (2.1.1 at the time).  After doing that gradle synced succesfully

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me on Mint 17.03 which is base off Ubuntu 14.04

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwchien/gradle
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gradle

Reopen Android Studio. Go to Run/Debug Configuration and there should be  an icon saying you need to Update gradle. Just click it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and no answer in stackoverflow helped. But I found the issue in my project. It was because my `.gitignore` file contained these lines:

```
# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear
```

and that is why git did not upload the `MyProject\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar` file to remote. So, I added this line to `.gitignore`:

```
!/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
```

Make sure you had this line too. At least this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal type gradlew clean. it will automatically download and install gradle version 2.10(ie latest gradle verson available)

Eg : C:\android\workspace\projectname>gradlew clean

Answer (score 0):

this work for me.

create a new project in android studio. Open project setting and copy the local gradle path. now open the project having gradle problem and paste that url and select local path.

click apply problem will get solved.

Answer (score 0):

Some cases it does not work-out because there is no problem in your project gradle or android-studio.

**Step 1:**

> Minimum supported Gradle version is 2.14.1. Current version is 2.11. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl

- Check gradle version in your system `gradle -version`
- Older version upgrade gradle version `brew install gradle`

**Step 2**

- Go to android-studio-> Preference-> Build,Execution,Deployment-> Gradle
- Use default gradle wrapper and un-mark offline work

**Step 3**

- Check `distributionUrl` in gradle-wrapper.properties
- Upgrade if older version.
- Clean Project

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade my version of Cordova to support the latest version of Gradle.  Updating the distributionUrl in GradleBuilder.js didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

if your has this error that **"supported Gradle version is 2.14.1. Current version is 2.4. "**, on terminal. means your should update your gradle.

On Mac OS: you can use **brew upgrade gradle**

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was indeed in the distributionURL in gradle-wrapper.properties file and Android Studio auto-fixed inserting

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-20170417000025+0000-all.zip

But this was a wrong URL. The correct one is

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions-snapshots/gradle-4.0-20170417000025+0000-all.zip

Apparently the url changed in gradle's API but not in Android Studio so fixing it by hand solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Latest gradle**

Download the latest gradle-3.3-all.zip from

**http://gradle.org/gradle-download/**

1.download from Complete Distribution link

2.open in android studio file ->settings ->gradle

3.open the path and paste the downloaded zip folder gradle-3.3 in that folder

4.change your gradle 2.8 to gradle 3.3 in file ->settings ->gradle

5.Or you can change your gradle wrapper in the project

6.edit YourProject\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties file and edit the field distributionUrl in to

> distributionUrl=
>   https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.0-all.zip

shown in **android studio's gradle files**

Answer (score -1):

File - setting - Build Execution Deployment - Gradle - Select 'Use default gradle wrapper(recommended)'

Comment: It would be better if you add a little bit explanation along with your answer.