# Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version

Tags: android-studio

Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to "aed79d567e57792ed352e708d2b7ca891ff897c6"
Can somebody help me? How could I update this one

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxxxx.xxxx.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}   dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/Parse-1.10.2.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'}'
```

and i'm using plugin `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'`

Do you have any idea which may be the cause?

Comment: OK. So *please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE* to the value it tells you. What part of those very clear instructions do you not understand? It tells you **exactly** what to do.

Comment: @kenwhite I don't understand anything. i'm already confused.. I have a dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
    }

Comment: As I said, the message tells you **exactly** what you need to do. Either upgrade the plugin or set the environmental variable to the value it provides for you. Short of someone driving to your house to work your keyboard fro you, what else do you want us to do?

Comment: I have the same issue. Does that ask to change the plug in 'com.android.application' to something else? And where do I need to set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I too had this problem.Solved it by going to project gradle file changed the class path from

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
}
```

1.5.0 looks stable to me .

Comment: I had been using gradle version 2.0.0-alpha3 and changing it to 1.5.0 as said by @Prince worked for me too.

Comment: Thank u for marking the answer useful @JayakrishnanSalim

Comment: @princejayakumar thanks a lot. it worked,,really appreciate it

Answer (score 14):

Update your plugin to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'
```

You may get an error saying `Gradle Version 2.10 is required`.

Follow [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34814536/3758898), which says:

> I gest you need change **Settings > Builds,Execution,Deployment >
>   Build Tools > Gradle >Gradle home** path
>
> Or you need set Use default gradle wrapper and edit
>   `Project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` files field
>   `distributionUrl`  like this
>
> ```
> distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
> ```

Comment: @tin if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @Sufian thanks for editing.