# Gradle version 2.10 is required, try editing distributionUrl

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting the following error when trying to build.

```
Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\Dylan\Dropbox\Work\PersDev\TutaMe\AndroidStudio\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

as you can see in my distribution URL. I have already edited it to version 2-10

How can I force android studio to update gradle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814368/gradle-version-2-10-is-required-error

Answer (score -1):

You need to update gradle Version in distributionUrl to the latest versions

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

instead of:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

Comment: If you look at the error message I posted in the question. It shows that I have already updated the string.