# Android Studio doesn't work fine with gradle 2.10 and gradle plugin 2.0.0-alpha5

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I use com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3 and gradle 2.8 before I update to Android Studio 2.0 preview 5.
It works fine.

After I update to 2.0 preview 5,it tells me to update to com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha5 and gradle 2.10.

I can't build and run my app normally now. It always uses a old copy of my code though I have changed the code and costs more time to build.

If I turn back to com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3 and gradle 2.8.It become right.

Android Studio Version (http://tools.android.com/recent)

Android Gradle Plugin Version (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)

Android Studio Preview 6 was posted on Jan 21, 2016.
Android Studio Preview 7 was posted on Jan 23, 2016.

You can see that the Android Studio Preview updates frequently.  If you don't want to deal all kinds of bugs, you would better to use a stable version.

If you want to use more features, you should always keep latest version to avoid bugs.

Comment: For production use you should not use alpha versions of the tools. Go back to a stable environment for day to day use. Alpha versions are there for people to try out and give early feedback.

Comment: @Henry I want to build faster.Old version takes too much time to build.

Comment: Think again, is it really faster if you run into problems?

Comment: I turned back to old version.But I want to use the latest version if possible.

Comment: What error do you receive? `I can't build and run my app normally now` is not enough to get help.

Comment: @Sufian I change some code .But when I run my app to my mobile, there is no change.

Comment: If it builds then this is not a gradle related error. Is "instant run" turned on?

Comment: instant run is turned on.

Comment: @tinysunlight then it is the problem. Gave me the same issue. Disable it and run again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with instant run, because if project builds and APK installs, it can't be Gradle issue.

**Instant Run** is still under development and has this issue of not working properly.

To disable the instant run:

1. open properties,
2. go to **Editor > Build, Execution, Development > Instant Run**,
3. uncheck **Enable instant Run to hotswap code**

Comment: I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: I update to alpha6  and turn off Instant Run.It works fine now.

Comment: @Sufian : Not able to uncheck my Instant Run on Android Studio . Any help?

Comment: "Not able to uncheck my Instant Run on Android Studio" do you mean it is checked and you can't uncheck? Also mention the version of gradle plugin (by pasting the line from .gradle file which looks like `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha7'`).

Answer (score 3):

There's a quick fix listed on google plus by the android dev team in the comments ([post](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/9PU97ynSdEb)).

Set dexInProcess equal to false in your build.gradle:

```
dexOptions {  
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"  
    dexInProcess false  //the magic line
}
```

Comment: looks like alpha8 is out, hopefully that solves your problem without this fix

Comment: Yes, new version of Android Studio  wroks fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this: go to project stucture from file-->menu or command-; in mac. Then (don't try changing the android plugin version to 2.10) change the android plugin version to same as your current android gradle build as illustrated in the image below:

[image]

Comment: All is right now. I just need to disable instant run.I hope google will fix it in new  version of Android Plugin.I will try alpha 7.

Comment: I was having an issue with the alpha7 so I gave this solution because it took me a lot of time to figured out. I also movef away from canary to dev for now

Comment: Current latest settings:
Gradle version: 2.12
Android Plugin Version: 2.0.0-beta7

Comment: it changes very often so be sure that the right version is used. I think now it updates automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Update your plugin to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'
```

You may get “**Gradle Version 2.10 is required.**” Error. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34814536/3758898)

Comment: I'm now using com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha5 and Gradle Version 2.10.

Comment: It will also work in com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha5

Comment: My gradle-wrapper.properties is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you must change the gradle versión settings and the wrapper file if you are using a local distribution.

1. **File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle**
2. Gradle Home to **gradle-2.10**
3. Apply
4. C:\Users\ ...\project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to **gradle-2.10-all**.zip

**if step 4 is missing, Android studio goes back to gradle-2.8, so i would have to do steps 1-3 every time.**

*Well it happens to me, i don't know if it is an isolated case.*

Answer (score 0):

If you have 64 bit distro, install 32 bit deps:
sudo apt-get install -y lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 lib32z1 lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install -y lib32ncurses5 lib32gomp1 lib32z1-dev