# Android Studio 2.0 Preview 8 issue with gradle 2.10 and plugin 2.0.0-alpha7

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I had some issues with Gradle plugin 2.0.0-alpha6 and Gradle 2.10 and solved them by disabling Instant Run (as stated in [Android Studio doesn't work fine with gradle 2.10 and gradle plugin 2.0.0-alpha5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915081/android-studio-doesnt-work-fine-with-gradle-2-10-and-gradle-plugin-2-0-0-alpha5)).

I then updated to gradle plugin 2.0.0-alpha7 without any issue

Today I updated Android Studio to the latest *2.0 Preview 8* version and I got the following error again:

> Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha7.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.0.0-alpha7/gradle-2.0.0-alpha7.pom
>       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.0.0-alpha7/gradle-2.0.0-alpha7.jar

Now, I see by clicking on those links that the two files don't exist... but, I get the same error if I revert to gradle plugin 2.0.0-alpha5 or 2.0.0-alpha6, do it doesn't make much sense. Is the maven environment down, maybe?

That's quite frustrating. Now, I tried to check whether Instant Run is enabled and I got a surprise: it's disabled and I cannot enable-disable it anymore, since Android Studio doesn't seem to understand I'm building using gradle.

[image]

Probably that's because it can't find the Gradle files, therefore doesn't let me enable/disable features that depend on te gradle plugin version. So, I don't know what to do.

I already incremented the max heap size in my build.gradle file

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

This is my full build.gradle file (except for some var settings I deleted from it): https://gist.github.com/MarKco/60f4ac63f7cafb783f3a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the release notes at  http://tools.android.com/recent

> We've just pushed Android Studio 2.0 Preview 8 to the canary channel,
>   as well as a new version of the Gradle plugin: 2.0.0-alpha8.  **You'll
>   want to update both**; instant run in particular is only enabled when
>   using the latest versions of both:

Therefore try updating the gradle plugin to 2.0.0-alpha8

Comment: It worked, thank you! I thought I could find the latest gradle-plugin version here: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/ but apparently I don't...

Answer (score 1):

To enable Instant Run again (or at least not greyed out) you have to update to gradle plugin 2.0.0-alpha8. This might also solve your other problems.