# Android build does not update the apk. Is there a way to prevent caching programatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, caching, bluetooth

I'm working on an app for myself to do the simple act of connecting to bluetooth devices!
when I try to build the app to my Nexus 5 phone from Android Studio, it seems to not build the most recent changes I made. It somehow looks like it cached the first build. It fixes the issue when I go to File>Invalidate Cache. But then when I try to build it again, it seems to have caches the next build. Is there a way to prevent caching programatically?
I had another app and it didn't happen to that one!

P.S. New to Android and Android Studio! :)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes and now it's working quite alright for me so thought I share it here to everyone else:

Go to `Run->Edit Configurations->Android Application->Application->Miscellaneous`
Uncheck "Skip installtion if APK has not changed" and restart your Android Studio.

Now it should build your APK all the time you build to your phone!

If this did not do the trick for you, try doing the same process by going to:
Go to `Run->Edit Configurations->Android Application->Miscellaneous`
Go to `Run->Edit Configurations->Android Native->Miscellaneous`
Go to `Run->Edit Configurations->Android Tests->Miscellaneous`

Then Sync your project with Gradle files and restart your Android Studio.

Comment: glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can go to

> File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployement -> Instant Run

and disable instant run.

By doing this Android Studio will build from scratch every time

You should also check the version of your Android plugin for Gradle.

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915081/android-studio-doesnt-work-fine-with-gradle-2-10-and-gradle-plugin-2-0-0-alpha5) for more information.

Comment: It not editable for me! It's checked and I cannot uncheck it!

Comment: Hm... it might be due to the version of your Gradle plugin then.

Comment: Added a couple of links that might help you out

Comment: I fixed the issue! Check out my answer below!
Thanks