# Android Studio Gradle Warning

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Android Studio on Ubuntu 12.04. I was using

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'
```

But I got an error saying plugin is too old so I changed aphla1 to alpha6

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'
```

But now I have a warning saying

```
Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /home/ameya/AndroidStudioProjects/myproject/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Accordingly I changed the distributionUrl from 2.8 to 2.10 but still the warning exists and it shows Gradle project sync completed with some errors.
Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Gradle Version 2.10 is required." Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814368/gradle-version-2-10-is-required-error)

Comment: You should use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'` .Let me inform .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the latest gradle-2.10-all.zip from

http://gradle.org/gradle-download/

download from Complete Distribution link

open in android studio file ->settings ->gradle

open the path and paste the downloaded zip folder gradle-2.10 in that folder

change the gradle 2.8 to gradle 2.10 in file ->settings ->gradle

Or you can change your gradle wrapper in the project

edit Project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties files field distributionUrl like this

[distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip](http://distributionUrl=https%5C://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip)

Comment: please up vote  this answer ,  its  worked in my  code