# Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8 Error

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-studio-2.0

Following things are using in the project-

> The android studio version - 2.0 Preview 4.
>   ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=9
>   ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=22
>   ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=22.0.1
>   ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=22

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha9'
```

As per the error I changed the distribution url

```
https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

to

```
https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

but still getting the following error

> Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>   Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
>   Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/manishpathak/Project/live/code/ICCCricketWorldCup2015Schedule/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip

Comment: Would this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34814536/450534?

Comment: remove the \ right next to https like this 
https: //services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip

Answer (score 11):

update your android studio version to 1.5.1. Your problem will be solved.
If your android version is updated. Try it out:

change **Settings > Builds,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle >Gradle home path**
OR

set Use default gradle wrapper and edit **Project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties** files field **distributionUrl** like this:

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

[try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814368/gradle-version-2-10-is-required-error?lq=1)

Answer (score 7):

You just need to update the path for gradle directory from gradle-2.8 to gradle-2.10

Steps:

Click on file ->settings ->gradle

Choose "Use local gradle distribution" radio button in the project-level setting

open and paste the path of the directory of gradle-2.10

( Note : Path will be similar to where gradle-2.8 was earlier present if you have done any update for android studio, or else you have to mention the path of download directory if you have downloaded the standalone gradle distribution from http://gradle.org/gradle-download/ )

change the gradle 2.8 to gradle 2.10 in file ->settings ->gradle

Apply the settings and rebuild the project.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**Option 1**

**First Try:** Update gradle-wrapper.properties file located in [Project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties] update distributionUrl
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip

***if above doesn't work follow following steps as well***

**Option 2**

**Step1:** **Check gradle version**: Gradle generally is installed in folder: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle[version number] eg gradle-4.1

**Step2:** **update gradle** is installed, download the gradle from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ for you download it https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-bin.zip and place it in studio gradle folder or some where else

**step 3:** 
**update gradle path** for (project specific or global as required) File > Settings > Builds,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle >Gradle home path
[image]

**Option 3**
File>Project Structure>Project>Gradle version, change it to 2.10
[image]

Comment: I think it should be accepted answer . Thanks @kunal-mahajan  for pointing out me to right direction. You saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

for this question 
change **File>Project Structure>Project>Gradle version** from 2.8 to 2.10
just so