# android.support.v7.widget.toolbar class is not showing in my any new project?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have typed Toolbar and IntelliSense give me class reference `import android.widget.Toolbar;` But not showing `android.support.v7.widget.toolbar`

I have created multiple new projects but still not working. my old projects where i used `android.support.v7.widget.toolbar` working fine.

I recently added android N package from SDK manager. May be this could be a reason.

gradle (project) setting :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle App setting :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "harry.com.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
}
```

Comment: call `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'`

Comment: set classpath `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta7`

Comment: i got this error `Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Volumes/BOOTCAMP/Android_Projects/MyApplication2/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814368/gradle-version-2-10-is-required-error/35147471#35147471

Comment: Still not working i have use gradle 2.12