# Android Studio Gradle Build Error after Update

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I just upgraded to the new Android Studio 2.0. When I started up the IDE, it prompted me to update gradle. I clicked yes. Now everytime I run my project, I get this build message

```
/Users/Package/app/build.gradle
Error:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.2.1. If
using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/
gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

How can I keep the updated version of gradle, so that I don't have to down-grade every time that I want to run the app.

Comment: Duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814368/gradle-version-2-10-is-required-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change the gradle url in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

Comment: Sorry but... Change `gradle url` to what? I believe this answer just repeats what the error message is already saying and if that worked people would not need come here to read it. It might as well just be something like "Follow the error message" and it would be as useful :(