# Upgrade Gradle version 2.8 to 2.10 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, classpath

I am trying to add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha5'` instead of `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'` to implement Google Plus signin. But gradle project sync ends with the following error.

```
Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /codes/MyProject/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Please suggest me the possible way to solve it.

Comment: what is your android studio virsion? 2.0?

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814368/gradle-version-2-10-is-required-error

Comment: Android SDK manager handles Android Studio updates and one of the checkboxes is build tools

Comment: @VivekMishra this solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest gradle version by opening gradle-wrapper.properties. It is in project/gradle/wrapper directory. 
Update distributionUrl

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip