# How to Update Gradle in Android Studio-

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am working on Android Studio and creating an app using Cordova. I wanted to use FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging) and its saying it requires Gradle Version 2.10 . I did it with changing the gradle version in build.gradle and wrapper but it ain't working.
The Error it is showing is

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.10.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/Users/shishir/Desktop/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.10/gradle-2.10.pom
file:/Users/shishir/Desktop/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.10/gradle-2.10.jar
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.10/gradle-2.10.pom
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.10/gradle-2.10.jar
Required by:
:android:unspecified
```

Also the above 2 links are empty

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814368/gradle-version-2-10-is-required-error

Comment: I tried that changing DistributionURL still it ain't working