# Unity3D Gradle version 2.10 is required

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I'm building a game for Android in Unity on OS X and I get this error.

```
  CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-4.0.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"
  
  stderr[

  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  * Where:
  Build file '[...]/UnityProject/Temp/gradleOut/build.gradle' line: 19
  
  * What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradleOut'.
  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
     > Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 4.0.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in [...]/UnityProject/Temp/gradleOut/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip
  
  * Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  
  BUILD FAILED in 1s
  ]
  stdout[
  
  ]
  exit code: 1
  UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
  UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
  UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
  UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
  Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
  UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
  UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
  UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
  UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Unity uses Gradle version 2.10 but apparently current version is 4.0.1 (Does this mean that my PC has defined a "default" gradle version somewhere?)

### EDIT (3rd May)

I managed to export the project, open it with Android Studio and there I could force gradle version 2.10 and Android plugin version 2.1.0
This way the project compiled and I was able to execute it on device.

Is there a way I can do something similar to this on Unity? or system-wide?

#### What I've done so far (without success)

- As suggested I looked for the file `gradle-wrapper.properties` but it does not exist, and since it's under the `Temp` folder it wasn't a very promising path.
- I tried to create such file and configure the `distributionUrl` as stated.
- Did `brew install gradle` and then on project's folder I tried `gradle wrapper --gradle-version 2.10`
- Uninstall Unity, delete `~/.gradle` folder. Reinstall Unity.
- Tried to install gradle using [SDKMAN!](https://gradle.org/install/#with-a-package-manager) (this also sets Gradle 2.10 as default)

#### My specific scenario

- Unity 2017.4.2f2
- macOS Sierra

That's pretty much everything, any ideas?

Thanks!

#### EDITS

- Added more unsuccessful attempts
- Added the full error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814368/gradle-version-2-10-is-required-error

Comment: Thanks @IntelliJAmiya but unfortunately I'm working with Unity, not IntelliJ or Android Studio, so most of those answers don't even apply to my problem

Comment: Are you using any plugins in your Unity project? If so, can you list them?

Comment: Hi @Programmer Nope, I'm not using any plugins (yet)

Comment: Ok, check back for my answer in few minuets.

Comment: Go to `C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\GradleTemplates` copy the "mainTemplate.gradle" and paste it to pastebin.com. Provide link to it it. I want to see what it looks like

Comment: Hi @Programmer It was on `Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/[...]` because I'm on mac.

https://pastebin.com/0WCTRVtE

Answer (score 1):

The most important part of the error is:

> If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in
>   [...]/UnityProject/Temp/gradleOut/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
>   to gradle-2.10-all.zip

It wants you to use *gradle-2.10*.

**1**.Go to `<UnityInstallationDirecory>\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\GradleTemplates`, then copy `mainTemplate.gradle` file to your `<ProjectName>Assets\Plugins\Android` folder.

**2**. Open the `mainTemplate.gradle` file you copied to the `<ProjectName>Assets\Plugins\Android` folder.

**3**.Find `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'` inside it.

Replace the *`gradle:2.3.0`* with the version the error is asking you to replace it to.

In your case, that should be *`gradle:2.1.0`* then save it.

Comment: The-same error? Can you add a screenshot to show where you put the mainTemplate file in your project?

Comment: It's under `UnityProject/Assets/Plugins/Android` as you can see here 
https://s7.postimg.cc/5uo47nm6j/Screen_Shot.png

Comment: You said you are not using plugin but there seems to be plugins in that folder. There is libs folder and other files which are blurred out and you also have a manifest file there. Those can be modifying your gradle file.